# Не выгружается документация из репозитория Git lfs

Tags: windows, git, документация, tfs, git-lfs

TFS установлен на винде, в этом TFS я создаю пайплайны.
Есть пайплайн в tfs, в пайплайне есть шаг скачивания документации

git clone https://%User%:%Pwd%@tfs.vwewvvf.com/tfs/vwewvvf/Faw/_git/Faw-Documentation $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Doc

он падает и выдает такую ошибку

Cloning into 'A:\agent-1.507_work\5501\s\Doc'...
2023-09-18T09:34:27.4535601Z Downloading Faw/Doc/╨Ъ╨╗╤О╤З╨╡╨▓╨░╤П ╨╕╨╜╤Д╨╛╤А╨╝╨░╤Ж╨╕╤П ╨┐╨╛ ╨┐╤А╨╛╨┤╤Г╨║╤В╤Г Faw.docx (326 KB)
2023-09-18T09:34:27.4537069Z Error downloading object: Faw/Doc/╨Ъ╨╗╤О╤З╨╡╨▓╨░╤П ╨╕╨╜╤Д╨╛╤А╨╝╨░╤Ж╨╕╤П ╨┐╨╛ ╨┐╤А╨╛╨┤╤Г╨║╤В╤Г Faw.docx (0d17ty1): Smudge error: Error downloading Faw/Doc/╨Ъ╨╗╤О╤З╨╡╨▓╨░╤П ╨╕╨╜╤Д╨╛╤А╨╝╨░╤Ж╨╕╤П ╨┐╨╛ ╨┐╤А╨╛╨┤╤Г╨║╤В╤Г Faw.docx (0f26cc1w0f78cdbc514db15ccd1c3f7d97683b2680b456f920t8e73761fa876): batch request: missing protocol: ""
2023-09-18T09:34:27.4801809Z
2023-09-18T09:34:27.4802918Z Errors logged to C:\agent-1.507_work\5501\s\Doc.git\lfs\logs\20230918T123427.4525886.log
2023-09-18T09:34:27.4803742Z Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
2023-09-18T09:34:27.4810103Z error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
2023-09-18T09:34:27.4850816Z fatal: Faw/Doc/╨Ъ╨╗╤О╤З╨╡╨▓╨░╤П ╨╕╨╜╤Д╨╛╤А╨╝╨░╤Ж╨╕╤П ╨┐╨╛ ╨┐╤А╨╛╨┤╤Г╨║╤В╤Г Faw.docx: smudge filter lfs failed
2023-09-18T09:34:27.4854903Z warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
2023-09-18T09:34:27.4855402Z You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
2023-09-18T09:34:27.4856017Z and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
2023-09-18T09:34:27.4856273Z
2023-09-18T09:34:27.5653260Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '128'.

Насколько я понял проблема в lfs, как я понимаю нет указателей на этот файл. Кто с таким сталкивался и как решили проблему ?

P.S. Данная проблема характерна только для этого репозитория, остальные работают нормально.

пробовал различные команды, но пока ничего не помогло.

Comment: гит не любит 866 страницу.  начни скрипт с `chcp 65001`

Comment: подскажи о чем речь? Что такое 866,где ты это увидел ?

Comment: русское название файла записано в 866, а гит работает только с UTF-8

Comment: ты думаешь что из за этого может не скачиваться ?

Comment: ты сюда поболтать пришёл или проблему решить?  ты попробовал способ, который я предложил?